# Why is my @foreach statement not working in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I am creating a Laravel eCommerce site and I am using Voyager for the back end. I've ran into an issue when creating the 'Orders' section of the site. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lo7vzO1Fto&list=PLEhEHUEU3x5oPTli631ZX9cxl6cU_sDaR&index=19

I am overwriting the voyager view 'read.blade.php' for my order table. I also have my BREAD linked to a Controller called OrdersController.php.

This file is as follows (the additional code that I have added in is below):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Voyager;

use App\Order;
use Validator;
use App\iamlush;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;
use TCG\Voyager\Events\BreadDataAdded;
use TCG\Voyager\Events\BreadDataUpdated;
use TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController;

class OrdersController extends VoyagerBaseController
{
    //***************************************
    //                _____
    //               |  __ \
    //               | |__) |
    //               |  _  /
    //               | | \ \
    //               |_|  \_\
    //
    //  Read an item of our Data Type B(R)EAD
    //
    //****************************************

    public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

        $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        $isSoftDeleted = false;

        if (strlen($dataType->model_name) != 0) {
            $model = app($dataType->model_name);

            // Use withTrashed() if model uses SoftDeletes and if toggle is selected
            if ($model && in_array(SoftDeletes::class, class_uses_recursive($model))) {
                $model = $model->withTrashed();
            }
            if ($dataType->scope && $dataType->scope != '' && method_exists($model, 'scope'.ucfirst($dataType->scope))) {
                $model = $model->{$dataType->scope}();
            }
            $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([$model, 'findOrFail'], $id);
            if ($dataTypeContent->deleted_at) {
                $isSoftDeleted = true;
            }
        } else {
            // If Model doest exist, get data from table name
            $dataTypeContent = DB::table($dataType->name)->where('id', $id)->first();
        }

        // Replace relationships' keys for labels and create READ links if a slug is provided.
        $dataTypeContent = $this->resolveRelations($dataTypeContent, $dataType, true);

        // If a column has a relationship associated with it, we do not want to show that field
        $this->removeRelationshipField($dataType, 'read');

        // Check permission
        $this->authorize('read', $dataTypeContent);

        // Check if BREAD is Translatable
        $isModelTranslatable = is_bread_translatable($dataTypeContent);

        // Eagerload Relations
        $this->eagerLoadRelations($dataTypeContent, $dataType, 'read', $isModelTranslatable);

        $view = 'voyager::bread.read';

        if (view()->exists("voyager::$slug.read")) {
            $view = "voyager::$slug.read";
        }

        $order = Order::find($id);
        $products = $order->iamlush;

        return Voyager::view($view, compact('dataType', 'dataTypeContent', 'isModelTranslatable', 'isSoftDeleted', 'products'));
    }
}
```

```php
$order = Order::find($id);      (this gets the order id)
$products = $order->iamlush;    (this gets the product info and is there retutned below)

return Voyager::view($view, compact('dataType', 'dataTypeContent', 'isModelTranslatable', 'isSoftDeleted', 'products'));
```

My override 'read.blade.php' is the same as the normal apart from one section:

```php
<div class="panel-heading" style="border-bottom:0;">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Products In Order</h3>
</div>

<div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:0;">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($products as $product)
            <li style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                <div>Product Id: {{ $product->id }}</div>
                <div>Product Name: {{ $product->name }}</div>
                <div>Product Price: {{ $product->presentPrice() }}</div>
                <div>Product Quantity: {{ $product->pivot->quantity }}</div>
            </li>
        @endforeach
     </ul>
</div>
```

This should return all the data held in my database but instead, I get this error:

[image]

### After comments

Here is my Order.php model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'billing_email', 'billing_name', 'billing_address', 'billing_city',
        'billing_province', 'billing_postalcode', 'billing_phone', 'billing_name_on_card',
        'billing_discount', 'billing_discount_code', 'billing_total', 'payment_gateway', 'error',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\iamlush')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

I believe that the line '$products = $order->iamlush' refers to my function 'products()' in my order model and should actually read:

```php
$products = $order->products
```

But then I run this, I get the following error:

[image]

I think the issue could be my migration table to create the order_product pivot table:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrderProductTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')
                ->on('orders')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');

            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')
                ->on('iamlushes')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');

            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('order_product');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$products = $order->iamlush;` this is not an array?

Comment: It isn't supposed to be an array, I think it points to my model

Comment: then it would be `$order->iamlush()` , may be

Comment: In your controller, do `dd($products);` before returning to see what it contains.

Comment: @Qirel, I have done that now and found that it returns null so there must be an issue earlier in that file

Comment: Might be an issue with the relation `iamlush` of `Order`.

Comment: What is the output of `dd($products);`???

Comment: it just outputs ```null```

Comment: @STA, I have updated my question to include the output of dd($order)

Comment: Don't post text as image

Comment: @RossCurrie Check the `Order` model, specifically the `iamlush` relation. That's probably where the issue lies.

Comment: @Qirel I have updated my question to include my Order Model and I think I know what the issue is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says Table not found.
You need to migrate your tables by typing in your terminal or command line `php artisan migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the top of your controller:

```
Use DB;
```

Always when I need to fetch or change data I need to use it.

Comment: That's only if you're using the DB facade, so not always. If you're using models (which you should for the most part), you don't need it. This isn't why the relation is returning null.